# How to connect/bridge those edges most efficiently?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges

How to connect/bridge those edges:

[image: picture1]

without nonsense like this:

[image: picture2]

thanks for your help :)

Comment: Select all the vertices and hit **F**.

Comment: imho there's a clear N-to-1 vertices ratio to be filled... how you would prefer it to be?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do it "without nonsense" since the other side has way more vertices than the other. You would need to either add some vertices to the farther side or remove some on the closer one. You should tell how you want it to end up so it would be easier to fix your problem.

Comment: I'd like to have one or two elements in between which each have less vertices so i can model it to my liking. Right now ~16 vertices are connected to one vertex, i want to have 16 connected to 8 connected to 1 for example.

Comment: http://topologyguides.com/tagged/step-down